# LC3: Getting weird y's as output when using TRAP x22 after LEA

Tags: assembly, lc3

**CONTEXT:**

I'm writing a program where the user is requested to input a "1" or "2", that value's ASCII value is added by -49, and depending if the sum is 0 or 1, a string will be printed.

**CONFLICT:**

When I simulated my code, I got [these weird y's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hAJF.png) in the console. I tried using LD instead of LEA, however that didn't fix anything. I also noticed [in my simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otx4E.png) that there wasn't a Case 2 String (CAS2S) anywhere, but I was able to see CAS1S. I don't know what this means, but I'm suspecting that it may contribute to my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**CODE:**

```
    .ORIG x3000

; INPUT REQUEST: Store input value into R0
START   TRAP x23

; FILL PROCESS: Put value -49 in address of FN. Load value in FN address (-49) into R4
    LD R4, FN

; CASE CREATION: Add -49 (R4) to input value (R0)
    ADD R3, R0, R4

; BRANCHES: If R3 = 0, execute Case 1 Instruction. If R3 > 0 (specifically if R3 = 1), execute Case 2 Instruction
    BRz CAS1I
    BRp CAS2I

; BRANCH CASES:

; CASE 1 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 1 String into R1. Print string in R1. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS1I   LEA R1, CAS1S
    TRAP x22
    BRnzp START

; CASE 2 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 2 String into R2. Print string in R2. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS2I   LEA R2, CAS2S
    TRAP x22
    BRnzp START

; STRING STORAGE: Store input patterns in Case 1 String and Case 2 String
CAS1S   .STRINGZ "1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"
CAS2S   .STRINGZ "1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"

FN  .FILL #-49

    .END
```

Comment: In Case 1, you are loading the address of the string to be printed into R1.  In Case 2, you're loading it into R2.  I have no idea which of these two registers `TRAP x22` uses, but it obviously can't be both of them...

Comment: Hmm.. Good point. I thought that `TRAP x22` used the most recently loaded register.

Comment: "The most recently loaded register" is not a meaningful concept.  Registers store nothing other than their numeric value; they don't maintain any sort of access history.

Comment: TRAP x22 (PUTS) will print out a string of characters pointed to by the address contained in R0.

Comment: I figured it out! I changed the LEA destination registers to R0. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but this is because the null terminated string you are trying to print needs to be in R0.